# libvirt fails to start

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtualization

I seem to have a problem with libvirt:

```
systemctl status libvirt-bin.service

,● libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since zo 2016-10-02 08:24:09 CEST
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
  Process: 1761 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status
 Main PID: 1761 (code=exited, status=6)

okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization dae
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Unit entered 
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Failed with r
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Service hold-
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Start request
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization dae
lines 1-15/15 (END)...skipping...
● libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled; vendor pres
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since zo 2016-10-02 08:24:09 CEST
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
  Process: 1761 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status
 Main PID: 1761 (code=exited, status=6)

okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization dae
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Unit entered 
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Failed with r
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Service hold-
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Start request
okt 02 08:24:09 harrypi-410-100nd systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization dae
```

~
How can this be solved ?

Comment: `libvirt` is something different than VirtualBox. To check why `libvirt` isn't starting you could examine the output of `journalctl -u libvirt-bin`

Comment: I tried this Thomas, the log is too long to copy/paste, but one of the lines says; cannot connect to netlink socket with protocol 0: Toegang geweigerd

Comment: hmm frustrating just cant understand why some questions get more attention than others.  Its almost like some contest, to me its learning and helping others. Also its very disappointing when your question is marked as duplicate wich maybe helpfull but sometimes its not helpfull at all. In general this site is positive when we keep it helpfull and motivate other people to understand linux . Just some thaughts this monday, have a wonderfull week everybody !!

Comment: Maybe you can post the output of `journalct` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it in your question.

Comment: i just reported this issue as a bug on launchpad :https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1629634

Comment: Hello @Mokum, I run into the same problem on a ubuntu server 18.04 and I cannot find the answer. Did you solve your problem? I am looking for some help

Comment: Hi George Sp , this is from launchpad: 
Workaraound is the same:

# kill `cat /var/run/libvirtd.pid`
# apt-get -f install